# Best advanced book in probability theory?

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I have read real and complex analysis, and Probability theory by Feller(Vol1 & 2). What is the next book I should read to go deeper into subtopics of probability theory?
Thank you!

Comment: As one answer posted so far demonstrates, this depends very much on the subtopics you are interested in. Any information on this?

Answer (score 8):

Revuz and Yor: Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion. 
Karatzas and Shreve: Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus.

Both are indispensable.

Comment: Thanks! After reading Brownian Motion and stochastic calculus, do you think I will be able to handle research papers in the topic? Just curious! :)

Comment: Nero, what about the other ones [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204999/further-reading-on-stochastic-calculus-analysis)? @AbirMukherjee Probably some. Maybe you want to check out my question

Answer (score 2):

Measure Theory and Probability Theory by Athreya, and Probability and Measure by Billingsley