# What is the difference between stochastic calculus and stochastic analysis?

Tags: stochastic-processes, terminology, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I guess one could say that [Calculus is just a non-rigorous version of Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32442/198044).

What about in subjects involving stochastic processes? I took up masteral classes called stochastic calculus. I plan to pursue a PhD with my dissertation in stochastic what? Calculus or Analysis? Some professors in mathematics department websites I've seen (including my own university's) say their area of research is "stochastic analysis" not "stochastic calculus".

When should I say Stochastic Calculus or Stochastic Analysis?

Comment: I feel like analysis had a lot of $\forall,\exists,\epsilon,\delta,<$ symbols, while calc has more $\int,\operatorname d\!x,\infty,=$ symbols. Not sure if my assessment is accurate.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Cool summary, but I'm primarily wondering how this applies to stochastic processes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stochastic calculus is to do with mathematics that operates on stochastic processes.

The best known stochastic process is the Wiener process used for modelling Brownian motion. 
Other key components are Ito calculus & Malliavin calculus.

Stochastic calculus is used in finance where prices can be modelled to follow SDEs. In the Black-Scholes model, prices follow geometric Brownian motion.

The Ito integral is one of the major components in stochastic calculus. It is defined as the integral

\begin{equation*}
\int HdX
\end{equation*}

where $X$ is a semimartingale & $H$ is a locally bounded predictable process. Note that we cannot use the generalized Riemann-Stieltjes integral because strong bounded variation is assumed & Brownian motion is not of bounded variation.

Stochastic analysis is looking at the interplay between analysis & probability.
Examples of research topics include linear & nonlinear SPDEs, forward-backward SDEs, rough path theory, asymptotic behaviour of stochastic processes, filtering, sequential monte carlo methods, particle approximations, & statistical methods for stochastic processes.

Something I am interested in is how probabilistic techniques can be used to settle problems in in harmonic analysis, such as proving the $L^p$ boundedness of the Riesz transform. For $f\in C^1_K:$

\begin{equation*}
||R_jf||_p\leq c||f||_p,~1<p<\infty
\end{equation*}

for some constant $c.$

A technique is to give a probabilistic interpretation of the Riesz transform before proving $L^p$ boundedness:

\begin{equation*}
R_jf(x)=c\lim_{s\to\infty}\mathbb{E}^{(0,s)}_{x}\int^{\tau}_{0}A\bigtriangledown u(Z_r)\cdot
\end{equation*}

where  $u$ is the harmonic extension of $f,~f\in C^{\infty}_K.$ Here $A$ is the $(d+1)\times (d+1)$ matrix with $A_{ik}$ zero unless $i=d+1,~k=j,$ in which case it is one.  Here, $Z_t$ is Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

I hope this is okay. I am happy to expand on any points in more detail if you would like.

Comment: Cool thanks George S. 1 Where's Brownian motion in the Ito Integral definition? 2 What do you think of the inclusion in this comment?http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805/whats-the-difference-between-the-various-stochastic-blah-tags#comment14188_3805

Comment: Oh also, does it make sense then for mathematicians to say their research is in 'stochastic calculus' ? Say for a PhD proposal, do I propose to research in 'stochastic calculus' or 'stochastic analysis' ? Going over your answer again, it seems indeed that the relationship between the two is very similar to the relationship between calculus and analysis

Comment: In the Ito integral definition, the measure you integrate with respect to is one-dimensional Brownian motion. Although it is my opinion, I agree with this inclusion. stochastic calculus is used to give a strong theory for stochastic integrals and it operators on stochastic processes. Stochastic analysis is the when rigorous analysis is involved, and includes topics such as Schramm Loewner evolutions.

I'm not really the most qualified on advising PhD proposals (I am a PhD student myself). I would check with a probabilist in your department or your supervisor.

Comment: Whoa man https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schramm%E2%80%93Loewner_evolution

Comment: Thanks for the extra reputation!

Comment: Wait George, how do you know all this if your research area is [Euclidean harmonic analysis and PDEs.] (http://math.stackexchange.com/users/230715/george-simpson) ? Was probability or stochastic whatever your previous research area or something?

Comment: I spent a good portion of time learning about the Beurling-Ahlfors transform and Iwaniec conjecture. These are closely related to martingales, and so I had to brush up on my probability fast. Harmonic analysis is very closely linked to probability. I think Elias Stein pointed that certain problems in harmonic analysis could be approached via probabilistic techniques (such as the Iwaniec conjecture on the $L^p$ norm of the Beurling-Ahlfors transform).

Comment: Broadly, my current research interests are Euclidean harmonic analysis, spectral theory, wave equation techniques and restriction estimates. When reading, I sometimes get a bit carried away and end up looking at other topics such as calculus of variations, representation theory and lie algebras.

Comment: Cool. CoV is used in Malliavin calculus, I read. Uh, are the things in your answer from your being carried away or brushing up on probability?

Comment: Both. I needed a good understanding of how harmonic analysis interacts with martingales to understand the Iwaniec conjecture, and I had not taken many advanced probability courses so I needed to teach myself topics on Brownian motion fast.

Comment: Cool. Alright thanks George Simpson. For being such an inspiration: o7